# Django/Python: How to use the If-Statement

Tags: python, html, css, django, if-statement

I would like to, If a file is selected, that a image is shown.

I wrote the {% if file.selected %} myself, because I couldn't find anything online.
I know this ptompt is wrong, but just to get an Idea, If someone selects a file, it should show the image, else the text.

I just need the right prompt.

```
    <div class="mystyle">
                    <div class="titleit">
  
<input contenteditable="true" placeholder="An Interesting Titel... " type="text" name="title" maxlength="100" required id="id_title">
                    </div>
                      <br><br><br>
                    <div class="options">
                        
                       {% if file.selected %}
                    <img class="preview" src="/media/fitmedia/california.jpg">
                      {% else %}
                    <p class="p-text">Upload a Picture or Video </p>
                    <input class="fileit" type="file" name="file" required id="id_file">
                  {% endif %}

              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about how your file is being selected?

Answer (score 0):

Templates are evaluated on the server, i.e. long before user-interaction happens in the browser. That means you cannot do what you want with django temmplate language constructs. Perhaps try javascript..?